# Can we add Area 51 to the Gen-U-Wine™ Stack Exchange pull down "All Sites" list?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, profile-page

Earlier, Cody Guldner asked if Stack Exchange could [Lower the rep amount needed for trusted user privileges on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181874/lower-the-rep-amount-needed-for-area-51). Cody recognized that there is an existing problem with the Area 51 site.  While I don't agree that lowering the reputation threshold is the answer, as outlined [in my response here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181879/155826), I do think that it's worth looking at how to increase participation in Area 51; specifically, how can we encourage users, who already have access to more advanced Area 51 privileges, to participate more?

In the "All Sites" section of the Gen-U-Wine™ Stack Exchange pull down list, sites are ordered by the user's reputation for all sites where that user has earned at least 200 reputation, as demonstrated in the following screenshot of my drop down list:

[image: Screenshot of my list of sites, ordered by reputation]

---

**As you can see, the list of sites are ordered according to my reputation as listed in the All Accounts section of my global profile:**

---

[image: Global list of all of my accounts from my global profile]

---

However, note that for me, in my global profile, Area 51 ranks #5. It's my fifth highest account.  However, in the Gen-U-Wine™ Stack Exchange pull down list, Area 51 isn't the fifth site in the drop down list. In fact, it doesn't appear in the list at all.

This means that I explicitly make it a point each day to visit Area 51 and participate.  For many users who have earned enough reputation to help out with their experience, the phrase "out of sight, out of mind" seems to apply, as a quick scan through high rep user accounts on the top user page shows a significant lack of activity and participation.

Perhaps we can bring back some of these higher rep Area 51 users by placing the link to that site in a more prominent location in the drop down list.  Burying it all the way in the footer of the sites makes it less visible and reduces it's significance as the driving force for growth on the Stack Exchange network.

Can we add Area 51 in the drop down according to reputation?

Comment: The dropdown isn't ordered by global rep. I don't know exactly how it *is* sorted, but I see slight variations even depending on from which site I check, and it *mostly follows* reputation, with variations, sometimes switching 2 or 3 around a bit.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - For me, it's always been reputation. As soon as my MSO rep exceeded my SO rep, the two sites switched places. Again, keep in mind this only applies to sites where you've earned at least 200 reputation. Sites where you don't have 200 reputation are ordered randomly. So for you, you only have 2 sites where this applies:  Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hmm missed the 200 requirement, but still it does seem to prefer sites with 125 over 101 (essentially no activity). Also, I'm very sure I didn't see MSO at all from one other site, not sure which now hehe.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - Since you only have 2 sites, you won't see the one you're on currently in the list, assuming you're already on one of those two sites. So if you're on MSO, you won't see MSO in the drop down list, but you should see SO at the top. Likewise, on SO you should see MSO at the top. On any other site other than these two, you should see SO at the top and MSO as the 2nd site. Hope this helps!

Comment: Haha thanks, learn something new every day I suppose  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area 51 was added to the list of all communities after the [top bar redesign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta):

> [image]

However, there are some things still "missing" from the request here:

1. The list is sorted only alphabetically
2. Area 51 is not being added to the "My Communities" list automatically, one needs to manually add it
3. Even when added to "My Communities" list, the reputation on Area 51 is not being displayed. Reason is technical, due to old/different engine/codebase.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how much this will help.

I know that I personally do not ever go to the "All Sites" tab. I have the sites I regularly visited bookmarked, so I can click them for easy access. That is how I get to all of the sites that I normally visit.

Maybe we could implement the "All Sites" change for the users that do look at that, but in addition, we could add a message that suggests bookmarking the page.

[image]

The word "bookmark" could bring up the pop-up that normally comes up when you want to bookmark a page

[image]

And then there would be an arrow that points to the bookmark bar. There could be some buttons that would have 3 responses

- "Remind me later" - brings reminder back in a few days
- "I did" - doesn't show again
- "I don't want to" - doesn't show again

Comment: Good suggestion, but I think it still needs to be a part of the actual workflow that users go through so it's visible. Speaking for myself, I have a ton of bookmarks I've just plain forgotten.